# How to factor out third degree cubic equations while only having x^3 and a constant?

Tags: limits, factoring, cubics

> Determine $$\lim_{x\to3}\frac{x^2-5x+6}{x^3-27}$$

I know how to factor cubic equations if they are of the form $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$, but what happens if you only have the $ax^3$ and the $d$, as in $x^3 -27$? A good explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Find a number whose cube is $27$. Cant give a better explanation :P

Comment: If your factoring method is any good, it should work with $b=c=0.$

Comment: give an example of how you factor $x^3 - 2x^2 + 5x - 4 = 0$, then we can see what you are having trouble with

Comment: i just uploaded a photo of the question, sorry for not being clear

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general identity:
$$ a^3 - b^3 = (a - b) (a^2 + ab + b^2) $$

Answer (score 1):

use that $$x^3-27=(x-3) \left(x^2+3 x+9\right)$$
after the formula $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$

Comment: it would be nice if you would explain how you got it

Answer (score 1):

The cubic $x^3 - c$ (with $ c \ne 0$) has one real root, the cube root $r$ of $c$. So over the real numbers it factors as
$$
x^3 - c = (x-r)(x^2 + rx + r^2)
$$
and two complex roots, $\omega r$ and $\omega^2 r$, where $\omega = (-1 + i\sqrt{3})/2$. You can find those with the quadratic formula for the second factor.

To find the limit in your question (added after my answer) you don't need to know anything about the complex roots.